# Accidentally created branch with name origin/master

Tags: git

In a fit of unbelievable stupidity I accidentally ran

git checkout -b origin/master

And now have a branch named origin/master which ruins everything.  Is it safe to just run

git -D origin/master?

I tried looking in the config for the branch but its not defined there.  Yet when I run git branch I see it.

):

Comment: a fair mistake, I've done worse. Don't feel ashamed.

Comment: I made a similar mistake yesterday. I wonder if it is possible to configure git to issue warnings/errors or ask for confirmation before creating a branch whose name matches a certain pattern. I know I can create a pre-commit hook, but I would like to prevent the error at the earliest step possible — when creating a branch.

Answer (score 16, accepted):

`git branch -D origin/master` will delete your local `origin/master` branch.

This will not delete your `origin`'s (remote) `master` branch.  Deleting your remote branches would be either:

(git 1.7.0)

`git push origin --delete branch`

or

`git push origin :branch`